# Facebook ios app not launching my app when clicking on shared posts

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9, applinks

**Update:**
I'm using Facebook version 48.0 and iOS 9.2.1

I have been struggling with Facebook-sharing and deep linking into my app on iOS9 for a couple of days now, and I just can't get my app to automatically launch when tapping on shared content.

Everything seem to work as expected on iOS8.

All I see when I tap a shared content is a blank page in the Facebook's own webview. 
Under the "Share"-button in the top-right corner I have options for opening the link in safari, and for opening my app. Both these options will actually open the app. But what I want is to be prompted to open my app directly.

The thing is that this actually works when I share my url from a browser.
The difference is that that one is a link-share, while the one I'm trying to share from my app is an open-graph share.

I am aware of similar questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463199/facebook-ios-app-not-launching-my-app-for-applinks-enabled-link)),  but none of the answers has worked for me. Probably because my setup is a bit different.

**My setup:**

Sharing to Facebook works, but I've included my sharing-code for the sake of completion.
I'm sharing a FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent using FBSDKShareDialog like this:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
shareDialog.fromViewController = self.parentViewController;

NSDictionary *properties =  @{@"fb:app_id": <fb_app_id>, @"og:type": @"video.other", @"og:locale": @"sv_SE", @"og:url": <url_to_applink_host>, @"og:title": @"Title", @"og:description": @"my description", @"og:image": <image_url>};

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"video.watches";
[action setObject:object forKey:@"video"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *ogContent = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
ogContent.action = action;
ogContent.previewPropertyName = @"video";



shareDialog.shareContent = [self getFBContentWithProperties:mutableProperties];
shareDialog.delegate = self;
shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;

if (![shareDialog canShow]) {
    shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;
}

[shareDialog show];
```

The url used for the content points to a generated website that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myappscheme://?type=series&contentId=61b768777300eb6e&providerId=3" />
        <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="<app_store_id>" />
        <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="MyApp" />
        <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
    </head>
</html>
```

And finally this is what my plist file looks like:

```
...

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myappscheme</string>
                <string>fbAppIdScheme</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>

...

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>12345</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyAppName</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>

...
```

I feel there must be something obvious I'm missing, or is it that the facebook's webview is broken?

Any hints or guidance is welcome!

**UPDATE**

Here is an example link: 
http://shared.streamler.tv/f883439972d67d733e2c855b1ce224c6d4b1c727

Comment: Can you share an example link people can use to test this out?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser I have updated the post with an example link.

Comment: @Dancar : example link not working